# Failing to access one of my API REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

Im following a udemy course on how to develop a REST API using Java and Spring Boot.
I successfully created the API but one of the endpoints returns a strange error when i try to access it.

[image]

I can access "api/categoria-produto" without any errors, but whenever i try to access "http://localhost:8080/api/produto" i get the following error:

```
Hibernate: select produto0_.prd_id as prd_id1_1_, produto0_.data_atualizacao as data_atu2_1_, produto0_.data_cadastro as data_cad3_1_, produto0_.ativo as ativo4_1_, produto0_.caracteristicas as caracter5_1_, produto0_.cat_id as cat_id12_1_, produto0_.descricao as descrica6_1_, produto0_.nome as nome7_1_, produto0_.tamanhos_disponiveis as tamanhos8_1_, produto0_.unidades_em_estoque as unidades9_1_, produto0_.url_imagem as url_ima10_1_, produto0_.valor_unitario as valor_u11_1_ from produto produto0_ limit ?
2022-06-26 12:24:41.975 ERROR 11428 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B225465
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
...
```

I already searched on the internet about java.io.StreamCorruptedException but cant find anything related to my problem or how to fix this.

Can someone give me some guidance on this?

Im a newbie in Spring boot and backend in general.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my Produto class:

```
package com.athosdev.fullstackecommerce.entities;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@Table(name="produto")
@Data //A anotação "Data" vem do lombok e gera os GETTERS e SETTERS de produto automaticamente
public class Produto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="prd_id")
    private Integer prdId;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", nullable = false)
    private CategoriaProduto categoria;

    @Column(name="descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="caracteristicas")
    private String[] caracteristicas;

    @Column(name="tamanhos_disponiveis")
    private String[] tamanhosDisponiveis;

    @Column(name="valor_unitario")
    private BigDecimal valorUnitario;

    @Column(name="url_imagem")
    private String urlImagem;

    @Column(name="ativo")
    private boolean ativo;

    @Column(name="unidades_em_estoque")
    private int unidadesEmEstoque;

    @Column(name="data_cadastro")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date DataCadastro;

    @Column(name="data_atualizacao")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date DataAtualizacao;
}
```

FULL error log:

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-06-26 12:38:40.555  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.a.f.FullstackEcommerceApplication      : Starting FullstackEcommerceApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-39LEKVK with PID 14628 (H:\Projetos Programação\Fullstack Ecommerce\Backend\fullstack-ecommerce\target\classes started by athos in H:\Projetos Programação\Fullstack Ecommerce\Backend)
2022-06-26 12:38:40.557  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.a.f.FullstackEcommerceApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-06-26 12:38:41.039  INFO 14628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-26 12:38:41.086  INFO 14628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-06-26 12:38:41.655  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-06-26 12:38:41.664  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-26 12:38:41.664  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-06-26 12:38:41.767  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-26 12:38:41.767  INFO 14628 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1171 ms
2022-06-26 12:38:41.976  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-06-26 12:38:42.015  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-06-26 12:38:42.145  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-06-26 12:38:42.219  INFO 14628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-06-26 12:38:42.382  INFO 14628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-06-26 12:38:42.395  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-06-26 12:38:42.932  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-06-26 12:38:42.938  INFO 14628 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-06-26 12:38:42.987  WARN 14628 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-06-26 12:38:43.890  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-06-26 12:38:43.898  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.a.f.FullstackEcommerceApplication      : Started FullstackEcommerceApplication in 3.63 seconds (JVM running for 3.929)
2022-06-26 12:38:55.036  INFO 14628 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-26 12:38:55.036  INFO 14628 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-26 12:38:55.037  INFO 14628 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
Hibernate: select produto0_.prd_id as prd_id1_1_, produto0_.data_atualizacao as data_atu2_1_, produto0_.data_cadastro as data_cad3_1_, produto0_.ativo as ativo4_1_, produto0_.caracteristicas as caracter5_1_, produto0_.cat_id as cat_id12_1_, produto0_.descricao as descrica6_1_, produto0_.nome as nome7_1_, produto0_.tamanhos_disponiveis as tamanhos8_1_, produto0_.unidades_em_estoque as unidades9_1_, produto0_.url_imagem as url_ima10_1_, produto0_.valor_unitario as valor_u11_1_ from produto produto0_ limit ?
2022-06-26 12:38:55.221 ERROR 14628 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B225465
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:761) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:517) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:482) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:163) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:202) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My JPA Repository:

```
package com.athosdev.fullstackecommerce.dao;

import com.athosdev.fullstackecommerce.entities.Produto;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "produto", path="produto")
public interface ProdutoRepository extends JpaRepository<Produto, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code with your API handler?

Comment: It's normal if I don't see any getter/setter and constructor?

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to use an `ObjectInputStream` to read something that is not serialized using Java serialization (which is a specific binary protocol).

Comment: @Samba im using Lombok, the ```@Data``` anotation generates the getters and setters to me

Comment: Hi @Kaan, do you mean my JPA repository? I will add it to the post